Error al generar el pdf: could not load type 'system.web.ui.control' from assembly 'system.web, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral (C#)
Quiero generar un pdf, para esto le mando la variable desde un cuadro de texto, pero me da un error, ya lei varios artículos y hacen referencia a la versión, pero estoy perdido, estoy usando visual 2022 y .net 8, y tengo instalado el crystal 13.0.33
Anexo imagen del error.
Primero me marcaba que algunas dependencias, ya las instale, tambien instale el crystal porque no se inicializaba, entonces ya no se que hacer.

Este es el codigo:
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string parameterValue = textBox1.Text; // Obtener el valor del TextBox
            string reportPath = @"C:\report.rpt"; // Ruta absoluta al archivo de informe

            // Llamar al método para generar el PDF
            GeneratePdf(reportPath, parameterValue);
        }

        private void GeneratePdf(string reportPath, string parameterValue)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!File.Exists(reportPath))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"El archivo de informe no se encuentra en la ruta: {reportPath}");
                    return;
                }

                var reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
                reportDocument.Load(reportPath);

                // Configurar el parámetro del informe
                reportDocument.SetParameterValue("ParameterName", parameterValue);

                // Configuración de exportación
                var pdfOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
                var exportOptions = reportDocument.ExportOptions;
                var diskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions
                {
                    DiskFileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "report.pdf")
                };

                exportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                exportOptions.FormatOptions = pdfOptions;
                exportOptions.DestinationOptions = diskFileDestinationOptions;
                exportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;

                // Exportar el informe a PDF
                reportDocument.Export();

                MessageBox.Show("PDF generado exitosamente en el escritorio.");
            }
            catch (TypeInitializationException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error de inicialización de tipo: {ex.Message}");
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error al generar PDF: Archivo no encontrado. {ex.Message}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error al generar PDF: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }







    }
}


Saludos Ignacio! Bienvenido a SO. El problema es extraño porque tu captura muestra un formulario desktop (Windows Forms o WPF?) pero el mensaje de error es de una App web (ASP.net WebForms o MVC?). Si es una app desktop, cambia momentaneamente el ´ex.Message´ por ´ex.toString()´ para que veas el stack trace. Entodo caso parece que tu proyecto hace referencia a una librería web que no debería.
